# Automate "Right-click + Print" on .xlsx files

Tags: excel, file, printing, automation

I need to automate the act of printing .xlsx file. 
I have already seen some answers to this task saying that it is possible by creating a VBA script, as well as some examples. That is not about what my question revolves around.

Thought, I know that it is also possible to right-click on a .xlsx file and click "Print", which does the exact task that I want. It opens Excel, prints the file to the default printer, then closes Excel. (Windows 7, by the way)

So I'm thinking that the work has already been done here.

What process is launched when clicking this "Print" option? Can it be launched via command line, or "clicked" by a python script or something? And if not, why? How can something so easy to click be impossible to automate? I assume a process of some sort must be launched in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

This task can be easily launched using python.

```
import os
os.startfile('C:/path/to/the/file.xlsx','print')
```

This code will launch the same print task. From there, it is pretty trivial for a python developer to automate the task in his scripts.

However, if you do not know much about Python and do not want to learn it now, an easy (or lazy?) way to add it in any automation script would be to save the two lines of code above in a `whatever.py` file, and launch it via command line (with Python installed, of course).

Answer (score 0):

The context menu print command for Office documents utilizes Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE) and does not directly run a command that can be replicated from the command line.

You can view the content of the commands in the registry. Browse to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlsx` and look at the (Default) data column. On my machine, "Excel.Sheet.12" is the type of a .xslx file. Then browse to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.12\shell\` to see the commands registered for that file type. On my machine, the Print (Default) is `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" /dde` and the "command" is `zn=BV5!!!!4!!!!MKKSkEXCELFiles>]-z5hw$l[8QeZZR4_X=$ /dde`, none of which is directly useful or accessible for running from a command line.

It *will* require another program to allow you to access the interface, but there are programs that allow you to make use of DDE from the command line. I recommend Freddy Vulto's [Class Exec](http://fvue.nl/wiki/ClassExec). More information and a few other similar utilities can be found [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ddecommandline.php).